# Match TableViewCell's Label from other TableViewCell's Label

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My problem is little complicated to define for me, even I understand what I am trying to do, I try my best to write this problem to understandable, guide me if I lack anything in question description.

So the problem is that I have a `UITableView` inside a `UITableViewCell`, both of `UITableViews` have  custom `UITableViewCell` classes. Datasource and delegate of both outer an dinner `UITableView`'s are in same class. I am handling the data array like this

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if (tableView==self.mainTableView) {
        return titleArray.count;
    }
    return timeArray.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    if (tableView==self.mainTableView) 
    { 
        MainTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWitentifier:@"cell"]; 
        cell.label.text = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
        return cell; 
    } 
    InnerTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"]; 
    cell.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor]; 
    return cell; 
}
```

My custom cell's description

1. Main `UITableViewCell` cusotm class properties - `UILabel` (eg.
   myLabel),`UITableView`(inside)
2. Inside `UITableViewCell` custom class properties  - `UIView` (eg.
   myView)

Now I want to show myView only on that cell when 'myLabel' matches with my array of string object. for eg.

```
if([myLabel.text isEqualTostring:@"22"]){
cell.myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

}

For eg. if I have 5 views and 2 label, now 2 rows in Main `UITableView` and 5 rows in inside `UITableView` but every view should be in the outer cell 
only if it matches the myLabel'text.

P.S Don't think about where matching data coming from its not an issue issue of matching data.

As a final conclusion I want to create different row count for each inner UITableView cell.

Comment: If I get your question right, so you want to hide myView if it do not myLabel.text with some NSString property you have, right?

Comment: It is like suppose if I have 2 cells in main table and 3 views to show in those two cells now views will get divided according to the match. But what is happening is main 2 cells showing all 3 views in both cells which becomes 6 views in total.

Comment: Have you tried any code to achieve this? Could you please show the code for tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method?

Comment: -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (tableView==self.mainTableView) {
      MainTableViewCell *cell  = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWitentifier:@"cell"];
        cell.label.text = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell;
    }
    InnerTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    
    cell.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    return cell;
}

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this?

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    if( tableView == self.mainTableView ) 
    { 
        MainTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWitentifier:@"cell"]; 
        cell.label.text = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
        return cell; 
    } 
    InnerTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    MainTableViewCell *parentCell = (MainTableViewCell*)cell.superView; 
    NSIndexPath *parentIndexPath = [self.mainTableView indexPathForCell:parentCell];

    NSString *text = [dataArray objectAtIndex:parentIndexPath.row];
    if( [text isEqualTostring:@"22"] //your condition goes here
    {
        cell.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor]; 
    }
    else
    {
        cell.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor]; 
    }

    return cell; 
}
```